# How to use conditional view in fuelphp?

Tags: fuelphp

I've a website built on fuelphp framework. I want to make a new version of this website with new design. I want to keep the both design.

I've thought the following two ways-

- Put a button on my website as Old UI / New UI or
- Use http://example.com/beta

As my changes would be only on views I don't want to duplicate all the controllers. I just want to load the views dynamically with a condition.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Themes would be perfect for this. It allows you to have different grouped sets of views that you can switch between by changing the active theme.

Documentation: http://fuelphp.com/docs/classes/theme/introduction.html